# Any $p$-order subgroup is normal in a $pk$ group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

I'm looking to prove that if $G$ is a group of order $pk$ where $p$ is prime and $p>k$, that any subgroup $K\leq G$ of order $p$ is normal in G.

Does anybody have any hints or tips for proving this? I've tried multiple approaches including induction on $k$, and haven't really gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the third Sylow theorem.

Consider how your subgroup of order $p$ acts on the whole group $G$ and what you can infer from the orbit-stabilizer theorem in this case.